# QGIS map composer remove red cross with condition

Tags: qgis, print-composer, image, picture

In the atlas composer, I'd like to be able to assess whether the path to the image is valid.

Something like, but I always have the "photo" attribute (an ID) filled in. I will check the path.

```
if ('/home/'|| "photo"||'.jpg' IS NULL,'/home/'|| "photo"||'.jpg' '/home/noname.jpg')
```

So when my image exists in the directory: display the image and if the image doesn't exist: display an image indicating 'no image'.

Or find a way to make the big red crosses disappear...
The condition may also work to avoid exporting the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`file_exists`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/de/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#file-exists) function:

```
if (
   file_exists ('/home/'|| "photo"||'.jpg'),
   '/home/'|| "photo"||'.jpg',
   '/home/noname.jpg'
)
```